# Kotlin FP : Convert List<String> to Map<String,Int>

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have a List of String, I want to transform into a Map of occurrences. ( ~ The Map values are the count of many times the String was repeated in the List)

The imperative way, I'd write like the following

```
fun transformMap(list: List<String>): Map<String, Int> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
    for(n in list){
        map.put(n,map.getOrDefault(n,0) + 1)
    }
    return map.toMap()
}
```

**How to write this in Functional Programming way ?**

In Java 8+, this will be written like this

```
String[] note;
Map<String, Integer> noteMap = Arrays.stream(note)
         .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
          collectingAndThen(counting(), Long::intValue)));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Kotlin's [`Grouping`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/index.html) to do this in one line via the `Iterable<T>.groupingBy` extension:

```
val myList = listOf("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a")
val myMap = myList.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()

println(myMap)
// Prints {a=3, b=2, c=1}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use streams in Kotlin too. But if you want to avoid streams, you can use `fold()`:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c", "a")
val histogram = list.fold(mutableMapOf<String, Int>()) { map, s ->
    map[s] = map.getOrDefault(s, 0) + 1
    map
}.toMap()

println(histogram)
```

Comment: The line with the map value reassignment can also be rewritten as `map.merge(s, 1, Int::plus)`, which can often be found in competitive programming problem solutions. :)

Comment: @JB , it was my first reflex to use a mutableMap and `fold` too.
Then the answer with `groupingBy` looks so elegant.